# Panda conditional and print

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

```
df1:
     15/12/2015  15/11/2015  15/10/2015
Stock                                    
AA             10          11          11
BB             20          10           8
CC             30          33          26
DD             40          80          60

df2:
       a   b   c
Stock           
AA     2  11  22
BB     4  14  33
CC     3  12  30
DD     5  16  40
```

I am trying to:

from `df1`:

- if (AA:15/12/2015) is less than (AA:15/11/2015) then print a new row with result.

then from `df2`:

- append to data to from df2 to stock and result of conditional.

The new row would contain:

```
stock   If statement    a    b    c
AA      True            2    11   22
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these DataFrames share the same index you can index using the mask:

```
In [11]: df1['15/12/2015'] < df1['15/11/2015']
Out[11]:
Stock
AA     True
BB    False
CC     True
DD     True
dtype: bool

In [12]: df2[df1['15/12/2015'] < df1['15/11/2015']]
Out[12]:
       a   b   c
Stock
AA     2  11  22
CC     3  12  30
DD     5  16  40
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to keep the boleen result and add the df2 dataframe data onto the df1 dataframe?

Comment: I think, i worked it out using - result = pd.concat([df3, df2], axis = 1, join = 'inner')

Comment: @beng986 that or a plain old inner join: `df3.join(df2, how="inner")`.

Comment: in addition is there a way to do this using a loop?

Comment: @beng986 why would you want to do that?

Comment: i have two different csv's, the first one, akin to df1, goes back 18 dates. I am trying to create a list of 15/12/2015<15/11/2015 true/false for stock AA, BB, CC, DD. When this is complete, it moves on the same true/false for stock AA, BB. CC. DD but for 15/11/2015<15/10/2015. The aim is to get a long list with the data akin to df2 attached.